# Forcing the edge between subgraphs to go left or right

Tags: graphviz, trie, dot, subgraph

I have a PATRICA trie for which I'm generating a GraphViz file. The internal nodes are the skip values and the edges are dotted 0 and solid 1. It is preferred that 0 is to the left of 1, giving an alphabetical order of the leaves. I re-arranged the order I visit the graph so `dot` gives this result. However, when I group them in trees in a forest using subgraphs, I can't seem to force `dot` to reliably respect the order for inter-subgraph edges.

```
digraph {
    rankdir=TB;
    node [shape = box, style = filled, fillcolor = lightsteelblue];
    // forest size 2.

    subgraph cluster_tree0 {
        style = filled; fillcolor = lightgray; label = "tree 0";
        // branches
        branch0_0 [label = "3", shape = none, fillcolor = none];
        branch0_0 -> branch0_1;
        branch0_1 [label = "0", shape = none, fillcolor = none];
        branch0_1 -> branch0_2 [style = dashed];
        branch0_2 [label = "1", shape = none, fillcolor = none];
        branch0_2 -> leaf0_1 [style = dashed, color = royalblue];
        branch0_2 -> leaf0_2 [color = royalblue];
        branch0_1 -> branch0_3;
        branch0_3 [label = "2", shape = none, fillcolor = none];
        branch0_3 -> leaf0_3 [style = dashed, color = royalblue];
        branch0_3 -> leaf0_4 [color = royalblue];
        // leaves
        leaf0_1 [label = "u"];
        leaf0_2 [label = "v"];
        leaf0_3 [label = "x"];
        leaf0_4 [label = "y"];
    }
    branch0_0 -> branch1_0 [lhead = cluster_tree0, ltail = cluster_tree1, color = firebrick, style = dashed];

    subgraph cluster_tree1 {
        style = filled; fillcolor = lightgray; label = "tree 1";
        // branches
        branch1_0 [label = "0", shape = none, fillcolor = none];
        branch1_0 -> leaf1_0 [style = dashed, color = royalblue];
        branch1_0 -> branch1_1;
        branch1_1 [label = "1", shape = none, fillcolor = none];
        branch1_1 -> leaf1_1 [style = dashed, color = royalblue];
        branch1_1 -> branch1_2;
        branch1_2 [label = "0", shape = none, fillcolor = none];
        branch1_2 -> leaf1_2 [style = dashed, color = royalblue];
        branch1_2 -> leaf1_3 [color = royalblue];
        // leaves
        leaf1_0 [label = "f"];
        leaf1_1 [label = "m"];
        leaf1_2 [label = "n"];
        leaf1_3 [label = "o"];
    }

}
```

On one graph it works fine, but it the subgraphs are reversed to the order I want them.

[image: Patrica tree.]

I reversed the order in the file and it still looks the same. I played around with it and I could get it turned around by `rank=same`, `ordering=out`, and `invis` edges somehow, but I want it to be programmatic. Is there any easy way to draw the red dotted line, representing 0, to the left, instead of to the right, of the solid line, representing 1?

Comment: Are you asking how to programmatically get "Tree 1" to the left of "Tree 0"?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want. That way the letters are in order. In ASCII, the 4th MSB of all the letters is 0 for tree 1 and 1 for tree 0.

Comment: How did you do it with rank=same, ordering=out, and invis?

Comment: I guess I could draw it backwards, "branch1_0 -> branch0_0 [lhead = cluster_tree1, ltail = cluster_tree0, color = firebrick, style = dashed, dir = back];" and it would order them the right way, but the wrong vertical spacing; it's difficult to predict. I tried a lot of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

OK, a total kludge, but probably fully scriptable.

First, your input somewhat reworked:

```
digraph {
    rankdir=TB;
    newrank=true  // helps
    graph [splines=false]
    node [shape = box, style = filled, fillcolor = lightsteelblue];
    // forest size 2.

    subgraph cluster_tree1 {
        style = filled; fillcolor = lightgray; label = "tree 1";
        // branches
        branch1_0 [label = "0", shape = none, fillcolor = none];
        branch1_0 -> leaf1_0 [style = dashed, color = royalblue];
        branch1_0 -> branch1_1;
        branch1_1 [label = "1", shape = none, fillcolor = none];
        branch1_1 -> leaf1_1 [style = dashed, color = royalblue];
        branch1_1 -> branch1_2;
        branch1_2 [label = "0", shape = none, fillcolor = none];
        branch1_2 -> leaf1_2 [style = dashed, color = royalblue];
        branch1_2 -> leaf1_3 [color = royalblue];
        // leaves
        leaf1_0 [label = "f"];
        leaf1_1 [label = "m"];
        leaf1_2 [label = "n"];
        leaf1_3 [label = "o"];
    }
  subgraph cluster_tree0 {
        style = filled; fillcolor = lightgray; label = "tree 0";
        // branches
        branch0_0 [label = "3", shape = none, fillcolor = none];
        branch0_0 -> branch0_1;
        branch0_1 [label = "0", shape = none, fillcolor = none];
        branch0_1 -> branch0_2 [style = dashed];
        branch0_2 [label = "1", shape = none, fillcolor = none];
        branch0_2 -> leaf0_1 [style = dashed, color = royalblue];
        branch0_2 -> leaf0_2 [color = royalblue];
        branch0_1 -> branch0_3;
        branch0_3 [label = "2", shape = none, fillcolor = none];
        branch0_3 -> leaf0_3 [style = dashed, color = royalblue];
        branch0_3 -> leaf0_4 [color = royalblue];
        // leaves
        leaf0_1 [label = "u"];
        leaf0_2 [label = "v"];
        leaf0_3 [label = "x"];
        leaf0_4 [label = "y"];
    }
    // position the clusters (trees)
    {rank=same    branch1_0 ->  branch0_1 [style=invis weight=0]} 
  
     // a kludge, we'll add this edge in later
     graph [comment="branch0_0 -> branch1_0 [color = firebrick, style = dashed  constraint=false weight=0 ];"]
}
```

The "problem" is the cluster-to-cluster branch, so we remove it (for the first dot pass).  And we add the invisible edge to position the clusters where we want them.
Run this input into **dot -Tdot >myfile.dot**.  This sets positions for all nodes & edges.
Run that thru gawk (any language) to un-comment the commented branch(s) and insert into the file.
Finally, neato -n2 -Tpng fixedfile >fixed.png
(yuck, but it works)

f=atrie4.gv;

```
T=png; F=`basename $f .gv`;dot -Tdot $f >$F.dot;
gawk '
$1~/comment/{
  sub(/[\t ]*comment="/,"")
  sub(/"[\],;]?[\t ]*$/,"")
  add[++a]=$0
  next
}
{oline[++o]=$0}
END{
  for (i=1;i<o;i++)print oline[i]
  for (i=1;i<=a;i++)print add[i]
  print oline[o]
}' $F.dot|
neato -n2 -Tpng >$F.$T
firefox $F.$T
```

Comment: That is truly amazing. Why `neato -n2` and why does turning splines off help?

Comment: The splines setting makes no difference, it was left over from a (failed) experiment.  This (https://www.graphviz.org/faq/#FaqDotWithNodeCoords) explains `neato -n` (or `neato -n2`) .  `-n2` isn't required, but why recalculate edges when I like the edges coming out of dot.  Again no difference in the final layout.